# Invite Facebook friends?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I would like to add a function to let the possibility to users to invite their Facebook friends.

My problem is that there is no documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios)

The website is down and I don't have any information. Is it still possible to do that in an app?

Comment: Site is down at this moment, but might be back online tomorrow.

Comment: it's been down for a week now ...

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs